# Copying files from Ubuntu 18.04 to Android device

Tags: 18.04, android, mtp

[I know this is duplicate but all the answers here didn't work for me.]

I am a life-long Windows user who has migrated to Ubuntu since 5 weeks.

I am trying to copy files to my Android tablet and for two days I am getting this error:
`libmtp error: could not send object`, and after I tried some solutions on and off this website, the error trasformed to `libmtp error: Unknown error`.

I must say, however, that copying file from my tablet to my Ubuntu works quite fine.

Can any one PLEASE help?

Comment: This is a thread from 2014 and refers to version 14.04. Is it useful? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1073658/edit) your question and add what you actually have tried.  Just telling us that you have tried everything doesn't tell us what you HAVE tried.  Please help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: I apologize if this seems obvious (it wasn't to me!): Did you turn on your android device and unlock the screen (and make sure it stayed unlocked) before moving the files?

Comment: @Rabbit, I've always turned it on and unlocked itm but never left it unlocked, and VOILA, it worked! I now can never know if one of the solutions I tried worked or it was my fault from the beginning!

Comment: @Graham, yes, I did. Did it work? I have to experiment with other devices to tell.

Comment: @Terrance, I just cannot name them, all these stuff are gibberish to me. I am really sorry!

Comment: @Rabbit maybe you could add that as an answer since it seemed to be the trick. Or MuAnwar96 you can add the answer yourself (in the answer section below)

Comment: Cool beans! I'm so glad I could help (if indeed it was that suggestion that helped in the end). I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try turning on your Android device and unlocking the screen (and make sure it stays unlocked / unlock it again) before moving the files.

Comment: Thanks for making your comment into an answer :) (Note to reviewers of LQP queue: this is apparently what worked for OP - please see the comments on the question.)

Comment: This fails to work in my case, the error persists. Any other solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [android-file-transfer](https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux). Take a look to the [latest AppImage (at end-2019)](https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux/releases/tag/v3.9).

Comment: No MTP device found